# Given a compact set, how to find a relative compact and connected neighborhood.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-compact connected manifold and $K\subset X$ be a compact set.

**Question**: How do I find a connected open set $U\subset X$ such that

$$K\subset U\subset\overline{U}\subset X$$ and $\overline{U}$ is compact?

It is trivial if the connectedness for $U$ is removed. So, is there a way to modify the usual argument to put the connectedness on $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose that $K$ is path-connected. Since $X$ is locally compact and locally path-connected, we can choose, for each $x\in K$, a path-connected neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ with $\overline{U_x}$ compact. Since $K$ is compact, we can go to a subcover $U_1,\ldots,U_n$. It is straightforward to show that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_n$ is a (path-)connected neighbourhood of $K$ with compact closure.

Now assume $K$ arbitrary. Since $X$ is connected and locally path-connected, it is (globally) path-connected.

Fix a point $k\in K$. For each $x\in K$, choose a path $P_x$ from $x$ to $k$. Apply the previous case to each $P_x$, i.e., find (path-)connected neighbourhoods $U_x$ of $P_x$ with compact closure and pass to a subcover $U_1,\ldots,U_n$.

Then $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ with compact closure. Moreover, $\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i$ is nonempty (it contains $k$), so $U$ is also (path-)connected.

Comment: This is too complicated, just use open ball neighborhoods of points in K.

Comment: @studiosus Yeah, I know it also works like that, but in this case (at least in the way I am thinking) we need a more general form of the statement in the fourth paragraph, for which I couldn't easily find a reference, and there are a few arguments by contradiction which are avoided in this solution.